# JVM freezing while trying to send email

Tags: java, email

I'm trying to send an email from my program using the following method:

```
    void sendEmails(Tutor t, Date date, Time time, String tuteeName, String tuteeEmail){
    System.out.println("sending emails");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

            SimpleDateFormat timeFmt =  new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
            SimpleDateFormat dateFmt =  new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMMM dd");         
            String datePrint = dateFmt.format(date);
            String timePrint = timeFmt.format(time);                
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                   @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });

            try {

        Message tutorMessage = new MimeMessage(session);

        tutorMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("laneycodingclub@gmail.com"));

        tutorMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(t.getEmail()));

        tutorMessage.setSubject("Tutoring Appointment Scheduled");
        tutorMessage.setText("Hey " + t.getName() + 
                            "\n \t You have a new appointment scheduled on "  + datePrint + " at " + timePrint + 
                            "with " + tuteeName + ". \n If you cannot make this appointment, please contact club leadership immediately. "
                            + "\n Thanks for helping out!");

        Transport.send(tutorMessage);

        System.out.println("Done sending");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    System.out.println("messagingerror");
                    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But when the program reaches this method, the GUI locks up and the program freezes. This is the first time I've tried to use email in a Java program, so I'm not sure where the hold-up is.

Comment: I suspect its unable to connect to SMTP server. Please check if the server is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better avoid sending emails synchronously.

Generally it slows the work of your application, and worse - it may freeze it, for example if the mail server is unreachable or doesn't response.

Use some asynchronous mechanisms.

I am sure in this case you have a problem with your mail server.

Use some standalone Java program to make sure that you can send emails at all with these server parameters.

Comment: there should be some way to set timeout to Transport

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: 465 is the correct port to use when sending email using gmail via SSL. However, when using TLS the correct port is 587.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling this method from an event handler in your GUI, you are effectively blocking the Swing Worker Thread as long as the function has not completed. Every GUI handling is done in one thread in Swing (or in SWT for that matter), so when you block the thread, the GUI can not be updated, i.e. it freezes.

You should never run long running jobs in the GUI thread. Instead, you should create a new Thread and call your function from it.